# AVPlayer not playing local videos

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avplayer

I've been struggling with this for some hours...
I'm trying to play a video I download and save using AVPlayer but nothing shows up.
What surprised me the most is that if I use Apple's sample url for testing http live streaming
that video does play. (http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8)
However, when I change the url to the local file path the video doesn't play. I recorded the video with the iPhone and verified that the format (.mov) is playable. Here is the code block:

```
AVPlayer *mPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] init];
//mPlayer = [mPlayer initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8"]];
mPlayer = [mPlayer initWithURL:filePath];
playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:mPlayer];
[[[self view] layer] insertSublayer:playerLayer atIndex:3];
[playerLayer setFrame:self.view.bounds];
[mPlayer play];
NSLog(@"Playing video at: %@", filePath);
```

Sample output:
`Playing video at: /var/mobile/Applications/B298EE7D-D95D-4CCC-8466-2C0270E2071E/Documents/394665262.174180.mov`

EDIT:
Solved by using [NSURL fileURLWithPath:local_url_string]

Comment: How is `filePath` created?

Comment: Thank you Martin! I solved it by using `fileURLWithPath`

Comment: You should not send multiple `init`/`init…` messages to the same object. You should create the AVPlayer only in that first line, as `[[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:…]]`.

Answer (score 5):

Just small piece of code:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"splash" ofType:@"mp4"];
NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
AVPlayer* player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videoURL];
```

Comment: my video is on the local server and I want to play it on my device.

Comment: @Rex just change NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://cdn3.viblast.com/streams/dash/vod-bunny/XXX.mp4"];

Comment: Yes I am using this one also. but that not play my video in device

Comment: @Rex can you give me a link to gist with your code?

Comment: i am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45854740/3607051). It works perfectly in Simulator. but when I run this on real device it shows [error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45854668/3607051). please help

Comment: @Rex can you upload part of the project to github for example? I want help you but I really don't get what is the problem with AVPlayer

Comment: @WINSergery My problem looks like that [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854668/local-video-play-on-real-device-iphone)