# Local Video Play on Real device Iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, video, wifi

Use [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bRhdFymK-eE) link I am trying to play a video on the simulator with `AVPlayerViewController`. That work on simulator perfectly. But when I am trying to play it on real Device. It doesn't work.

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import  AVFoundation

class SafaribroserViewController: UIViewController {

var playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
var playerView = AVPlayer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
 
}

@IBAction func hsdgfsf(_ sender: Any) {
    let fileURL = NSURL.init(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/macmini/Downloads/QRCodeReader-master 3/QRCodeReader/small.mp4")
    playerView = AVPlayer(url: fileURL as URL)
    playerViewController.player = playerView
    present(playerViewController,animated:true) {
        self.playerViewController.player?.play()
    }
}
```

> output on real device

[image]

> Note:- My real device is connected to MacMini Hotspot.
>
> How Can I Play video on my real device? Thanks

Comment: Check this out it may be helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34265411/iphone-simulator-plays-video-real-device-wont

Comment: @Leo My video path does not exist in the project resource

Comment: It seems `fileURL` doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

i think you have problem  with your path

```
let fileURL = NSURL.init(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/macmini/Downloads/QRCodeReader-master 3/QRCodeReader/small.mp4")
```

just add  small.mp4  to your bundle of your app project

and use this

```
 let urlpath     = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "small", ofType: "mp4")
    let fileURL         = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: urlpath!)
```

Comment: Can I play the video out of the bundle resource? My video is on the local system folder

Comment: how Device will see your local System folder , are device see your Download folder :)  , Simulator can see it because its xcode is just program install on your Mac , but what about device

Comment: I am connecting my Device with local system Hotspot(wifi).

Comment: can't access your path  this not physical connection

Comment: how can I access the local system file on the real device any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("small", ofType: "mp4") 
let fileURL = NSURL.init(fileURLWithPath: path)
 if (fileURL)
 {
  print("Video url is not empty")
 }
```

**And Also Check video in Copy Bundle Resources**

---> Project

```
  ---->Target
  ---->BuildPhase
  ---->Copy Bundle Resources-->Add small.mp4
```

Comment: I m  not add video in resource, my video is outer resource

Comment: how can I access the local system file on the real device any idea?

Comment: Have you checked this condition  if (fileURL)

Comment: This is code for local system file. if you want to save video in document directory than you can get from directory

Comment: how that possible please guide me

Comment: Real device you can not access path, Because device path is different . i think you are silly mistake in the code. Why  you are path passing this /Users/macmini/Downloads

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152711/discussion-between-sara-methuz-and-lalit-kumar).